# Colour the square space

Tags: pattern, visual

[image]

To complete the image above, what colour should each of the white squares be?

Comment: I added a possible missing tag.  If you feel that it doesn't fit the puzzle, I won't be offended if you roll it back

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The image shows

> the solar system and some moons.

The colors correspond to

> the first letters of their names:
>
> The Sun and Saturn are dark red;
> Mercury, Mars, and the Moon are red;
> Venus is orange;
> Earth is yellow;
> Jupiter is light green;
> Uranus is green;
> Neptune is light blue;
> Phobos is blue;
> Deimos is dark blue.
>
> Assuming that the four moons of Jupiter shown are the Galilean moons, Io is purple, Ganymede is light grey, and Callisto is dark grey. The white square represents Europa, which must be **yellow** because it starts with the same letter as Earth.
>
> The last picture shows the Sun again, not Saturn. The blue square is Pluto, whose orbit is sometimes closer than Neptune's. The white square, representing Neptune, should be **light blue**. (Thanks to @2012rcampion.)

Comment: ....Nice.  Hadn't considered it.

Comment: How about [Pandora also has a 3:2 mean-motion resonance with Mimas](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandora_(moon))

Comment: @PaulEvans It's possible, but I don't see a compelling reason to choose Pandora rather than Phoebe or Prometheus. The Galilean moons have resonances with each other and they're not shown with crossing rectangles.

Comment: Pan is the second-closest orbiting body listed on Wikipedia... might be `qnex erq` as the answer...

Comment: I think the crossing orbits are (N)eptune = cyan and (P)luto = navy.  The central body matches (S)un = crimson.